# when i join two tables null values are not returned. Previous data is returned

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, yii2

In yii2 i write the left join query joining the two tables.

If the base table have only one record and the joining table has two records..

The `intProject_Id` is the common field for both the tables

I need if the one record having one value is null means it return Null..

Now the Previous data would be shown here.

My Controller code:

```
$model2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(['tbl_sprint.*','tbl_iteration.*'])
->from('tbl_sprint')
->leftJoin('tbl_iteration', 'tbl_iteration.intProject_Id = tbl_sprint.intProject_Id')
->where('tbl_iteration.intProject_Id = :intProject_Id', [':intProject_Id' => $projectid])
->all();
```

My joining Table:

[image: This is my joining table]
MyBase Table:

[image: This is my base table]

I want the output like:
[image: This is my out table.. iwant the text null or blank space in the sprint name column of the clearanz2 iteration]

Kindly help me to fix this

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for a different type of join. [Have a look here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Please try with following query.

```html
$model2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(['tbl_sprint.*','tbl_iteration.*'])
->from('tbl_sprint')
->innerJoin('tbl_iteration', 'tbl_iteration.intProject_Id = tbl_sprint.intProject_Id')
->where('tbl_iteration.intProject_Id = :intProject_Id', [':intProject_Id' => $projectid])
->all();
```